# Dynamically changing HTML whilst running python script in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, web-applications

I want to create a webapp for my ML project. I have this code in flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    
    return(
        render_template('index.html')


    )
```

The problem is that the index function returns the render_template. Instead, I want to run some python code from my ML project and at the same time update the HTML in index.html as the code runs.

For example, imagine you have some python code:

```
print('Reading text from csv file...')
dataframe = pd.read_csv('helo.csv')
print('Done reading...')
```

How can I have this code run in flask, but instead of printing; I change the innerHTML of a

tag in my main html file?

Comment: learn more about templates in Flask - you can send arguments with different values and then you can get HTML with different values. - `render_template('index.html', data=dataframe)` But it will need reload full page. If you want to update without reloading then you have to lear JavaScript and AJAX (`XHR`) or use JavaScript's module like `jQUery` which has function `$.ajax()`.

Comment: if you want to work with DataFrame on web page then maybe use special modules for this - [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html), [dash](https://plotly.com/dash/), [streamlit](https://www.streamlit.io/). Some of them are based on `Flask`

Comment: BTW: you can even use `df.to_html()` to render `<table>` which you can display in HTML `render_template('index.html', table=df.to_html())`

Comment: Thanks! I was originally using streamlit, but the problem is that it is reruns the whole script each time the user interacts with the UI. My program is quite long and consists of a number of sequential processes, all of which I want to display to the user on the UI and which they can interact with. Thats why I thought Flask works better, and as you say I may need to use AJAX. Essentially, all I want to do is run my usualy python program but instead of have inputs such as input('Enter number of clusters') etc, which  appears in the python console, I want it to display on a webpage/app

Comment: And then as the user inputs to the webapp, the python code continues running until the next input/plot. Then, the html on the webapp has to change to ask for this input. User inputs, then python code continues running. Repeat until program finishes

Comment: it seems you have complex code and you will need complex code in JavaScript to do it in Flask. `Flask`/`Django`/ etc. are web page frameworks for general use - they are not specialized for Data Science (ML, etc) and you will have to build from scratch something similar to `streamlit`, `dash` or `bokeh` or rather `jupyter`:)

Answer (score 1):

You could use XMLHttpRequest in javascript. So the browser will have the index.html loaded and than in the background. It could ask the server some data every few or so seconds (use setTimeOut for this). Once the server confirms it's done running the ML code. The browser could automatically react to it.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp